# Radial Labels on Mindmap - Part I

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

How can I modify the orientation of text in the nodes of a mindmap, such that the text is oriented radially from the center in the case of the outermost nodes.

For example, in the below diagram, I seek for the text INSIDE the orange circled nodes to be rotated so that it is in alignment with the direction of the orange lines respectively.

[image: Radial Mindmap]

Code for the above mindmap is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[small mindmap,concept,text=white]
    node[concept] {Bla} [clockwise from=-15]
    child[concept color=red,text=black]{
      node[concept]at(1,0){Bla Bla}[clockwise from=90]
      child[concept color=red!95!black,text=black]{
        node[concept]{A}[clockwise from = 120]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=red!75!black,text=white,grow=50]{
        node[concept]{B}[clockwise from = 80]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {B.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {B.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {B.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=red!50!black,text=white ,grow=10]{
        node[concept]{C}[clockwise from = 40]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {C.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {C.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {C.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=red!25!black,text=white,grow=-30]{
        node[concept]{D}[clockwise from = 0]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=red!10!black,text=white,grow=-70]{
        node[concept]{D}[clockwise from = -40]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.C}}
      }
    }
    child[concept color=green,text=black, grow=195]{
      node[concept]{Bla Bla}[clockwise from=80]
      child[concept color=green!10!black,text=white]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 50]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=green!25!black,text=white,grow=120]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 90]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=green!50!black,text=white,grow=160]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 130]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {B.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {B.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {B.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=green!75!black,text=white ,grow=200]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 170]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {C.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {C.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {C.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=green!95!black,text=black,grow=240]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 210]
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.A}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.B}}
            child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.C}}
      }
    }
    child[concept color=orange,text=black, grow = -90] {
      node[concept]at(-1.5,-2.5){Bla Bla}[clockwise from=10]
        child[concept color=orange!95!black]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from = 40]
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.A}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.B}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {A.C}}
        }
        child[concept color=orange!75!black, grow = -30]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from =0]
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {B.A}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {B.B}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {B.C}}
        }
        child[concept color=orange!50!black, text=white, grow=-70]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from =-40]
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {C.A}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {C.B}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {C.C}}
        }
        child[concept color=orange!25!black, text=white, grow=-110]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from =-80]
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.A}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.B}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {D.C}}
        }
        child[concept color=orange!10!black, text=white, grow=-150]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from =-120]
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {E.A}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {E.B}}
                child {node[concept,scale=0.5] {E.C}}
        }
    }    
   ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

UPDATE: Continue this topic in [Part II](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88276/radial-labels-on-mindmap-part-ii), seeking elliptical or rectangular radially rotating nodes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two and a half problems to solve here.

## 1. The Mathematical Problem

We have to calculate the amount of rotation.

The `counterclockwise from` argument is saved internally in `\tikz@grow@circle@from@start`.

For every child the amount of `/tikz/sibling angle` get added (`counterclockwise`) or subtracted (`clockwise`). The number of the child is saved in `\tikznumberofcurrentchild`.

For the orange children which are all placed in a clockwise matter the angle the text must be rotated is:

```
  \tikz@grow@circle@from@start
- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}) * (\tikznumberofcurrentchild - 1)
```

### ¿zʞıʇ

If a node’s content shouldn’t be upside down the formula has to be adjusted:

```
(
     \tikz@grow@circle@from@start
     - (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}) * (\tikznumberofcurrentchild - 1)
) + 180 * (
      cos(
            \tikz@grow@circle@from@start
          - (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})+(\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1)
      )
      < 0
)
```

## 2. The Rotation Problem

Great, so an easy

```
rotation =   \tikz@grow@circle@from@start
           - (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}) * (\tikznumberofcurrentchild - 1)
```

should do, right?

Nope:

[image]

The whole node gets transformed (in this case: rotated) which means that all anchor nodes
are rotated, too. And this confuses the calculation of the `circle connection bar` decoration. The more we rotate a child the more the connection bar gets twisted.

We surely could adjust the code for the `circle connection bar` decoration, but [that’s a lot of code](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymindmap.code.tex)!

It would be much easier to just rotate the text itself.
With the help of `graphicx`’s `\rotatebox` macro this can be easily done:

```
\newcommand*{\rotateme}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        \tikz@grow@circle@from@start-
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})*(\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1)
    }%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{\pgfmathresult}{#1}%
}
```

## 2½. The Node Text Problem

Do you want to edit every node that should get rotated and add the `\rotateme` macro?
I didn’t think so!

My solution collects all the node’s text with the help of

- `execute at begin node`,
- `execute at and node`, and
- the `lrbox` environment
  which saves the node’s text in a box called `\rotatenodebox`.

This box is then given to the already-mentioned `\rotateme` macro.

```
\tikzset{
    conc3/.style={concept,scale=.5},
    orange/.style={
        conc3,
        execute at begin node={\begingroup\begin{lrbox}{\rotatenodebox}},
        execute at end node={\end{lrbox}\rotateme{\usebox\rotatenodebox}\endgroup},
    }
}
```

## Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\newsavebox\rotatenodebox
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rotateme}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        \tikz@grow@circle@from@start-
        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle})*(\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1)
    }%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{\pgfmathresult}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    conc3/.style={concept,scale=.5},
    orange/.style={
        conc3,
        execute at begin node={\begingroup\begin{lrbox}{\rotatenodebox}},
        execute at end node={\end{lrbox}\rotateme{\usebox\rotatenodebox}\endgroup},
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[small mindmap,concept,text=white]
    node[concept] {Bla} [clockwise from=-15]
    child[concept color=red,text=black]{
      node[concept]at(1,0){Bla Bla}[clockwise from=90]
      child[concept color=red!95!black,text=black]{
        node[concept]{A}[clockwise from = 120]
            child {node[conc3] {A.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {A.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {A.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=red!75!black,text=white,grow=50]{
        node[concept]{B}[clockwise from = 80]
            child {node[conc3] {B.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {B.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {B.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=red!50!black,text=white ,grow=10]{
        node[concept]{C}[clockwise from = 40]
            child {node[conc3] {C.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {C.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {C.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=red!25!black,text=white,grow=-30]{
        node[concept]{D}[clockwise from = 0]
            child {node[conc3] {D.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {D.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {D.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=red!10!black,text=white,grow=-70]{
        node[concept]{D}[clockwise from = -40]
            child {node[conc3] {D.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {D.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {D.C}}
      }
    }
    child[concept color=green,text=black, grow=195]{
      node[concept]{Bla Bla}[clockwise from=80]
      child[concept color=green!10!black,text=white]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 50]
            child {node[conc3] {A.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {A.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {A.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=green!25!black,text=white,grow=120]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 90]
            child {node[conc3] {A.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {A.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {A.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=green!50!black,text=white,grow=160]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 130]
            child {node[conc3] {B.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {B.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {B.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=green!75!black,text=white ,grow=200]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 170]
            child {node[conc3] {C.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {C.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {C.C}}
      }
      child[concept color=green!95!black,text=black,grow=240]{
        node[concept]{Bla}[counterclockwise from = 210]
            child {node[conc3] {D.A}}
            child {node[conc3] {D.B}}
            child {node[conc3] {D.C}}
      }
    }
    child[concept color=orange,text=black, grow = -90] {
      node[concept]at(-1.5,-2.5){Bla Bla}[clockwise from=10]
        child[concept color=orange!95!black]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from = 40]
                child {node[orange] {A.A}}
                child {node[orange] {A.B}}
                child {node[orange] {A.C}}
        }
        child[concept color=orange!75!black, grow = -30]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from =0]
                child {node[orange] {B.A}}
                child {node[orange] {B.B}}
                child {node[orange] {B.C}}
        }
        child[concept color=orange!50!black, text=white, grow=-70]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from =-40]
                child {node[orange] {C.A}}
                child {node[orange] {C.B}}
                child {node[orange] {C.C}}
        }
        child[concept color=orange!25!black, text=white, grow=-110]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from =-80]
                child {node[orange] {D.A}}
                child {node[orange] {D.B}}
                child {node[orange] {D.C}}
        }
        child[concept color=orange!10!black, text=white, grow=-150]{
            node[concept]{Bla}[clockwise from =-120]
                child {node[orange] {E.A}}
                child {node[orange] {E.B}}
                child {node[orange] {E.C}}
        }
    }
   ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Crazy! Very impressive.